# Bash string manipulation based on token

Tags: string, bash, shell

I tried searching for this and couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

I have a variable in Bash/Shell that contains an email address. I would like to extract everything that comes before the "@" sign and put that into a new variable.

So `user@example.com` should be just `user`.

All the string manipulation looks for a length and position. The position should always be 0, but I really need to find that "@" token.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string on a delimiter in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
email="foo.bar@example.com"
user=${email%%@*}
echo "$user"
```

`${email%%@*}` consists of `${..}` (parameter expansion) with the parts `email`, the variable; `%%`, the operator to delete the longest match from the end of the string; and `@*`, a glob pattern matching @ followed by anything.

Comment: +1 for the built-in method. I just showed an alternate way but I would go with this method too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bash` string substitution (considering the fact that it is an email address and cannot have two`@` signs)

```
$ var=user@example.com
$ echo "${var/@*/}"
user
```

Comment: No idea why this perfectly valid answer got DVed.  +1 to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with `cut`, that splits a string by a delimiter character and extracts one of the resulted substrings (or "fields"):

```
echo $ADDRESS | cut -d@ -f1
#                     ^   ^
#              delimiter  extract first field
```

Comment: Or use a here-string `cut -d@ -f1 <<< "$ADDRESS"`.  The parameter expansion answers will be faster than spawning a `cut` process though.